# Is there any way to access variables of parent class in python as in java?

Tags: java, python

As I'm studying both Java and Python, I got curious about whether it is able to access parent variables using `super` keyword as in Java language.

In Java, it would be like

```
public class Parent {
   int var = 222;
}

public class Child extends Parent {
   int var = super.var
}
```

but in Python, this will raises error

```
class Parent:
    var = 222

class Child(Parent):
    var = super.var
```

I know it can be used as `Parent.var` instead of `super.var`, but it seems not good because it doesn't show it is the variable of its parent.
Is there any way to use parent variable in child class as in Java?, if not, simillar one?

Comment: You can use  inheritance see this  https://youtu.be/an59YHkdK9A and this https://youtu.be/J2_DHndMW9s

Comment: why would you do `int var = super.var` - just use `var` it is inherited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it via `self` reference, because `Child` inherited `var`.

Try this:

```
class Parent:
    var = 222

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.var)

child = Child()
print(child.var)
```

Comment: Shouldn't 'var' be an instance field in class Parent? (you have it as a static field)

Answer (score 1):

The original Java code has 'var' as an instance field in the base class. The equivalent Python would be:

```
class Parent(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 222

class Child(Parent):

    def inst_method(self):
        var = self.var  # temp copy of self.var
```

Note that it doesn't make sense for 'var' to be an instance field in the 'Child' class as in your original Java code (probably not allowed in Java anyway), but perhaps as a local variable as a temporary copy of the base class field.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Parent:
    var = 222

class Child(Parent):
    print("from inside class ", Parent.var)


print("from class obj ", Child().var)
```